# Java methods in xsl not available

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xalan

I'm using some Java methods in xsl like below :

```
<xsl:variable name="inSDF" select="SimpleDateFormat:new($datePattern)"/>
```

When i'm executing xsl from Eclipse with Xalan processor, its ok. But when I'm executing on server within a software with the same Xalan version, I get the following error :

> XalanXPathException: The function number
> 'java.text.SimpleDateFormat:new' is not available

Why does this error occur ? What should I check on the server ?

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps a configuration/installation issue? Does https://xalan.apache.org/xalan-j/faq.html#faq-30 apply? Or is there some security setting enabled on the server that blocks Java reflexion?

Answer (score 1):

The XalanXPathException looks like a Xalan-C exception, not a Xalan-J exception.  Is your server is running Xalan-C?  Your code looks like it trying to call a Java constructor, but that won't be available in Xalan C.

If you're trying to format a date in XSLT 1.0 running on Xalan-C, the documentation indicates it supports the EXSLT library.

- https://apache.github.io/xalan-c/extensionslib.html
- http://exslt.org/date/date.html